# SharePoint error after adding SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer webpart

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, report-viewer

We created a new wiki page. Then, we add a new webpart to this page -> SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer webpart.

Now the page gives error.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for error is because the Reporting services is not configured for the SharePoint installation via central admin -> General Setting -> Reporting Services Integration

Also, note that for SharePoint 2013 we do not have to configure the Reporting via Central admin -> General application settings -> Reporting service integration. This is specifically for SQL 2008 or 2008 R2. That is the configuration panel for SharePoint Reporting Services 2010.  You use it if you want to integrate SharePoint 2013 with an existing SharePoint 2010 SSRS service.

If you have installed the Reporting services 2013 via the SQL server installer, then in SharePoint you need to create a service application instead.

http://rajeshagadi.blogspot.in/2013/07/installing-reporting-services-in.html